# I can not see the meaning of this serious piece of js code

Tags: javascript

These lines are in the Mozilla pdf js viewer. They should be correct. But to me they look like:

```
a = b;
if (b !== a) {
    // do something
}
```

Here are the lines:

```
function webViewerPageNumberChanged(evt) {
    var pdfViewer = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer;
    pdfViewer.currentPageLabel = evt.value;
    if (evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageNumber.toString() && evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageLabel) {
        PDFViewerApplication.toolbar.setPageNumber(pdfViewer.currentPageNumber, pdfViewer.currentPageLabel);
    }
}
```

Could somebody shed some light?

---

The above code lines are in `viewer.js` in `pdfjs.1.9.426_dist` - `line 2194`. 
Judging by the following getters/setters at `line 8842` Ivan's answer seems to be correct:

```
}, {
    key: 'currentPageNumber',
    get: function get() {
        return this._currentPageNumber;
    },
    set: function set(val) {
        if ((val | 0) !== val) {
            throw new Error('Invalid page number.');
        }
        if (!this.pdfDocument) {
            return;
        }
        this._setCurrentPageNumber(val, true);
    }
}, {
    key: 'currentPageLabel',
    get: function get() {
        return this._pageLabels && this._pageLabels[this._currentPageNumber - 1];
    },
    set: function set(val) {
        var pageNumber = val | 0;
        if (this._pageLabels) {
            var i = this._pageLabels.indexOf(val);
            if (i >= 0) {
                pageNumber = i + 1;
            }
        }
        this.currentPageNumber = pageNumber;
    }
}, {
```

Comment: `var b = NaN;` :) but yes, this is ugly. Or maybe there are some funny getters / setters in the background?

Comment: !== operator checks the value and type. It is making sure it is a string value.

Comment: @Prins look at line 3, `a` has the same value and type as `b`

Comment: my take is that the if(evt.value...) is checking 2 conditions:  1. that the displayed page is not the one you want, and 2. that the pdfviewer is still accessible (by double-checking if the currentPageLabel was set correctly).

Comment: @JonasW. but can `evt.value` be NaN? Do you think that's why they put that in?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeWbpw?editors=0010) line 2112

Comment: Can you please link to the context in the code on github?

Comment: Found it: [**here**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/98cabb388a838b151c2d999e3266d10b900af5d1/web/app.js#L1991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [line 1991 of pdf.js/app.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/98cabb388a838b151c2d999e3266d10b900af5d1/web/app.js#L1991) a comment just before the `if` statement reads:

> Ensure that the page number input displays the correct value, even if the
>   value entered by the user was invalid (e.g. a floating point number).

So maybe `NaN` could be a potential value for `evt.value`. In this case as [Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) said `evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageLabel` would return `false`.

```
function webViewerPageNumberChanged(evt) {
  let pdfViewer = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer;
  pdfViewer.currentPageLabel = evt.value;

  // Ensure that the page number input displays the correct value, even if the
  // value entered by the user was invalid (e.g. a floating point number).
  if (evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageNumber.toString() &&
      evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageLabel) {
    PDFViewerApplication.toolbar.setPageNumber(
      pdfViewer.currentPageNumber, pdfViewer.currentPageLabel);
  }
}
```

I hope this will help.

---

**Edit:** Indeed user1919163, you were right.

I got this response after [making a pull requestion to change `line 1998`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/9800):

> I don't think this fix is correct. While it looks like we're comparing the variable to itself, **currentPageNumber is actually a quite elaborate setter**; see

```
set currentPageNumber(val) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(val)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid page number.');
  }
  if (!this.pdfDocument) {
    return;
  }
  // The intent can be to just reset a scroll position and/or scale. 
  this._setCurrentPageNumber(val, /* resetCurrentPageView = */ true);
}

/** 
 * @private 
 */
_setCurrentPageNumber(val, resetCurrentPageView = false) {
  if (this._currentPageNumber === val) {
    if (resetCurrentPageView) {
      this._resetCurrentPageView();
    }
    return;
  }

  if (!(0 < val && val <= this.pagesCount)) {
    console.error(
      `${this._name}._setCurrentPageNumber: "${val}" is out of bounds.`);
    return;
  }

  let arg = {
    source: this,
    pageNumber: val,
    pageLabel: this._pageLabels && this._pageLabels[val - 1],
  };
  this._currentPageNumber = val;
  this.eventBus.dispatch('pagechanging', arg);
  this.eventBus.dispatch('pagechange', arg);

  if (resetCurrentPageView) {
    this._resetCurrentPageView();
  }
}
```

> Therefore, it does more than just an assignment. After the logic is complete, we want to check if the condition holds.
>
> Unless there is a visible bug (and if so, please open an issue for it), I think this is fine.

Comment: Who issues the PR for replacing that ugly thing with `Number.isNaN(evt.value)` ?

Comment: Done! [checking if the user's input (page number) is NaN](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/9800)

Answer (score 0):

This function is probably binded to a scroll event. When its executed checks if the current page matches the displayed page. If not, it updates the displayed page.

I asume `evt.value` contains the currentPage number.

```
if(currentPageNumber != displayedPageNumber){
    /* update page number*/
}
```

Comment: But why would it check `evt.value !== pdfViewer.currentPageLabel` when the previous line is `pdfViewer.currentPageLabel = evt.value;`?